# How to bind code behind variable value to javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript header `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com?Key=">`
This `Key` is in aspx.cs like `string Key="123456";` How can I bind this `Key` value to the javascript header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access code behind variables in aspx files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com?Key=<%= Key %>">
```

Comment: `The name 'Key' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Is Key a method variable? What is its scope?

Comment: @DGibbs I would use some client side scripting

Comment: `src` is a 3rdparty api content source

Comment: note that `Key` must be public or protected and must be defined in scope of page code behind class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1-make your script referrable by code-behind by adding an id and runat="server" attributes:

```
<script id="myScript" runat="server" type="text/javascript">
```

2-in code-behind, on page_load, add the src attribute dynamically:

```
this.myScript.Attributes.Add("src","http://example.com?Key=" + Key);
```

You're done!

Answer (score 0):

Code behind:

```
public Key { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Key = "123456";
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com?Key=<%= Key %>">
 </script>
```

Comment: Too much code. It's enough to just render proper key from server side, as OP wants.

Comment: I see more then one js function with 3 lines of code. It's: script tag with function (7 lines); body onload handler; server-side `asp:HiddenField` control; 4 lines of code-behind; Two other answers is one-line solution, and it more correct, because it's no need to perform any actions on client in this particular case.

Comment: Yep, that's better. One more note: you should define `Key` autoproperty outside of function, and you don't need to check if ispostback.